# Safari - Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[data-card-type="payment-one

Tags: jquery, safari, syntax-error

on mac Safari (and older versions of FF v.38 and older) we are receiving the following error:

**Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[data-card-type="payment-one"**

jQuery Version: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js

```
$(this).change(function() {
  if($(this).val() != '' ) {
    $('input[data-card-type="'+paymentGroup+'"').val('').prop('disabled',true);
```

In Safari's Console, in red it reads:
*Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[data-card-type="payment-one*
and beneath the error it reads:
*(anonymous function)*

Does any of this look like it conflicts with jQuery 2.1.4, or maybe there is something else incorrect?

Comment: They missed the closing bracket! 
Everyone here rocks!
Thank you thank you! FANTASTIC!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This looks like it's a Safari issue, but really it never should have worked. You need to close the `[data-card-type=paymentGroup` statement, without that ending `]` Safari will throw a fit. I know this from experience. Chrome (my main dev browser) will let this fly without a single peep, but Safari breaks (and rightfully so, its not valid).

Replace your code with this:

```
$(this).change(function() {
   if($(this).val() != '' ) {
     $('input[data-card-type="'+paymentGroup+'"]').val('').prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ericjbasti! That was it... works perfectly! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yes every browser except Safari on Windows and iPhone let this error slip through!

Comment: I'm so dumb xD Thank you, I was thinking about Safari compatibility problems but It throws the error even in Chrome APP for iOS. That made me thought it was me indeed. Thanks!